# How can I manage the SELinux context of a docker container?

Tags: docker, selinux

tl;dr: Is there a way to run a docker container in the callers SELinux context?

I am running a bunch of different docker images on different (mostly RH-based) servers for building/testing purposes.

Imagine an automated flow like this:

1. checkout sources
2. run on CentoOS 7
3. run on Ubuntu 18.04
4. run on Fedora 30

One particular feature of this setup is that all docker containers work on the same (versioned) source files, bind-mounted into `/src`. Earlier on, I discovered I had to supply the SELinux mount options `:Z` or `:z` for the container to get access to the files checked out on the host.

Due to a design decision, the containers also have access to the other container's build artifacts through `src`. And apparently the relabeling of `/src/` can take minutes on a host system that has a rather large build history.

I could of course try to restructure things or use `--security-opt label:disable` on the containers. But I wondered why the relabeling is necessary in the first place. Could I not simply run the containers in *my* context? They basically work like a sophisticated `chroot` in that setup and do not expose any public services.

Bonus question: What, exactly, does `--security-opt label:disable` do?